# Convert for loop results into array in bash

Tags: bash, unix

I have a table with column called "names".  Can i store each name into different variable?

Right now I am using a for loop and storing the results into single variable.

```
for j in `psql database_name -U admin -c "select names from table;"`
     ; do
done
```

When i do echo$j  it prints below result

```
  tom
  Harry
  steve
```

How do i store each values(names) in different variables?

Comment: are you using a database?  How are you pulling the data out?  And what kind of output are you looking for? Like this? `$x="tom"; $y="Harry"; $z="steve"`? (i.e., what variable names do you want?)

Comment: I am pulling  'tom' , 'Harry' and 'steve' from database and i want to store each name into different variable

Comment: From what database and how are you pulling the variables? How are you comunicating with the database? What is the format of data pulled out from the database?

Comment: psql database_name -U admin -c "select names from table"

Comment: Wouldn't an array be more suitable here? Anyways, if your really really want a new variable for each entry then you have to specify how these variables should be named, for instance `var1`, `var2`, `var3`, ...

Comment: @Socowi . How do we store the results into an array?

Comment: Right know I cannot tell because I don't know how you obtain your input. Please fix your code. I think the `psql ...` should be inside a subshell `$(...)` and the last quote has no corresponding closing quote. Please run your code before pasting it here.

Comment: @Socowi Code fixed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating one variable per value is impractical. Think about it: How would you access these variables? What you want is an array.

You can define the array as follows:

```
mapfile -t names < <(psql database_name -U admin -c 'select names from table;')
```

This will add every line printed by `psql` as an entry of the array `names`. To access the entries use `${names[0]}`, `${names[1]}`, and so on. The size of the array is `${#names[@]}`.

---

Since the question is called »*Convert for loop results into array in bash*« here's another way to build up the array. However, I wouldn't use a `for ... in $(...)` loop here as names with spaces will be split and symbols like `*` will expand.

```
names=()
for name in $(psql database_name -U admin -c 'select names from table;'); do
    names+=("$name")
done
```

If you want the loop to run some additional commands use the first approach in this answer and loop over the array – this is safer:

```
mapfile ... # see above
for name in "${names[@]}"; do
    # do something with $name
done
```